# JSON file_get_contents is not working small example included

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

Do you know why this doesn't work ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="" content="">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$json_url="http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=titanic&y=1997";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$info=json_decode($json);
print_r($info);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The CodeLobster inspector will show all the php-lines but no error given, nothing happens. When running the code directly in IE or Firefox, no error msgs, nothing happens. PHP and Apache is up running, and other PHP-programs works fine. allow_url_fopen = On

This example is taken from http://99webtools.com/get-movie-info-imdb.php
The example works OK when the clicking Sample Request

Kind Regards
Torbjorn Ljung
Sweden

Comment: It would be more helpful if instead of just saying "it's not working," you post the error messages you get

Comment: What isn't working? Does it not save? Do you get an error? Does your server catch fire? Does it automatically start sending loads of spam to your users? Does your database hack itself? Does the server start making weird beep-beep-beep noises? Does the browser crash? Does Windows change its password? Do your users complain from lack of sight? Hearing? Do they get seizures? **What isn't working?**

Comment: Nothing seems to happen. If I open this html-file in Firefox nothing happens. CodeLobster which is an editor have an inspector which will mark the php-lines.

Comment: When I see a question saying "it doesn't work" without explaining *in which way* it doesn't work, or that there was an error without specifying what the error was, I'll vote to close as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" 9 times out of 9. You're not giving anyone a starting point for examining the problem. Explain what you're trying to accomplish, what results you're getting and how they differ from the intended results, and include any error messages you received. Also, please edit your question to clarify and add information rather than responding in comments.

Comment: Please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule".

Comment: OK I see what you mean. But in this case I don't get any response whatsoever :-( Only the debugger highlights the php-lines without any comments. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use [curl](https://php.net/curl)

```
$url="http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=titanic&y=1997";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
print_r(json_decode($result, true));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast response. But it didn't work the inspector marks all of your code :-( <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="" content="">
</head>
<body>
$url="http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=titanic&y=1997";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
</body>
< I have the allow_ set to ON in PHP-INI.

Comment: @user3437733 Did you remember PHP tags? Is PHP running?

Comment: @user3437733 It work fine for me,The issue is related to your php

Comment: Yes PHP is running, just checked it out.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to find out what's wrong ? I must leave now but will be back in a few hours. Please be very specific if you find out what I should do to run new tests :-)